# Spring messages are not getting logged using log4j?

Tags: spring, log4j

I am using log4j in spring MVC web application.

Log messages by other frameworks like hibernate are getting logged but not by spring etc.

Below is my log4j.properties.

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FILE

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=E\:\\logs\\pe.log

log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=10240KB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n


log4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO
log4j.logger.org.springframework.rules.values=INFO
log4j.logger.org.springframework.context.support=INFO
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=INFO
log4j.logger.org.springframework.aop.interceptor=INFO
log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=INFO
log4j.logger.org.springframework.security.event.authentication.LoggerListener=INFO
```

Comment: If all your spring loggers use the INFO level, which is the same as your root logger, then it should not be needed to define them. This is useful if you want to override some settings of logger along the hierarchy.

Comment: @Fradenger. I changed root logger at debug level. Still no luck.

Comment: I imported your config file and it works fine for me. Are you sure Spring really sends stuff to the logger when your run your code? You can try to log something through a spring logger like this: `LogFactory.getLog(org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.class).info("test spring logger");` Works fine for me.